# How to use Scala match/case against Collection type without triggering compiler warning

Tags: scala

My code is analyzing a structure returned via JSON.  I take the parsed JSON and use a match/case to determine if I have a Map[String,Any] before further processing.  It works fine, but the compiler warns me about type erasure, specifically, as I understand it, because the type String is unavailable at run time.  This no problem for me in terms of functionality because it is sufficient for me to simply know that we have Map.  But I appreciate the warning and would prefer to code it in a way that makes explicit that such runtime checking is not occurring and to eliminate the warning.  I tried simply coding Map instead of Map[...] but that does not compile.  I also tried Map[Any,Any] but that still generates a warning.

I am seeking recommendations.

Also, I am puzzled about why a later case using List[Any] does not cause a similar warning to be issued.

Here is the code fragment:

```
  // Parse JSON result - returns List[Any] or Map[String,Any], depending...
  val jo = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(json)
  //println("\nParsed JSON structure: "+jo)
  jo match {
    case Some(v)  => {
      val pjo = jo.get
      println()
      pjo match {
        case p: Map[String,Any] => {
          //println("Is a Map")
          val eList = p.get("error")
          if (eList.size > 0) {
            println("Errors:")
            for (e <- eList) println(e)
            println
          }
        }
        case p: List[Any] => println("Is a List")
        case p => println("Is a "+p.getClass.getName)
      }
    }
    case None => println("JSON parsing returned None")
  }
```

warning:

```
... X.scala:149: non-variable type argument String in type pattern Map[String,Any] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

Comment: I recommend using something like play-json which parses into a strongly typed class, or a typed JsObject.

Comment: I looked at about six different JSON handlers before settling on this one - in spite of it being deprecated according to what I read - because of simplicity.  It's just "there" already!  I am considering the Play framework for another purpose so your recommendation is welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an underscore:

```
case p: Map[_, _] => ...
case p: List[_] => ...
```

Comment: Heh, underscore, of course. Thank you. That means I have to follow with a cast in the next line like this: `p.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]].get("error")` which is fair enough, I suppose.  Yet I still don't undertand why I see no warning for List[Any]. (?)